# Extracting values from lists in json file using R

Tags: json, r, nested-lists

I am quite inexperienced in using R and I have to complete a script for a school project.
I have a json file with nested lists and I have to retrieve values contained in two attributes. The problem is that these attributes are in different lists inside my file. So I tried this:

```
`grabInfo<-function(var){
   sapply(json_data.rows, function(x) returnData(x, var)) 
}
returnData<-function(x, var){
     if(!is.null( x$doc$payload[[var]])){
           return( trim(x$doc$payload[[var]]))
       }else if(!is.null(x$doc$sensorType == 'movement')){
            return( trim( rbind(x$doc$value, x$doc$date_inmilli)))
        }else {
             return(NA)
         }
}
fmDataDF<-data.frame(sapply(c(1,3), grabInfo), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`
```

In the first `if` (so the first kind of list) I extract values contained in `var` (in particular the first and third attribute). When it comes to the second list, I have to check if it is the right sensor (data are dirty), but I cannot use the var because "value" and "date_inmilli" are in different positions (`c(3,5)`, so I had to code directly where to find them...I know...horrible) and in my dataframe instead of having two values in the two columns, I have two vectors (value, date) for each column.

Could you help me fix this?  I hope I was clear enough.

An example with just 2 rows of my file json_data (from which I made a subset`json_data.rows <- json_data[['rows']]` used in the script) is showed below:

`{"total_rows":99019,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"5f238411f1d877723c8e5f7a40c1fa3f","key":"5f238411f1d877723c8e5f7a40c1fa3f","value":{"rev":"1-7625857a2f79af0e46c2b73fdbde986e"},"doc":{"_id":"5f238411f1d877723c8e5f7a40c1fa3f","_rev":"1-7625857a2f79af0e46c2b73fdbde986e","value":0,"date_human":"2017-04-12T03:44:20.803Z","date_inmilli":1491968660803,"sensorType":"movement","date":"2017-04-12T03:44:19.902Z"}},
{"id":"0006d0a04d14c4cf0158db1a9a185dac","key":"0006d0a04d14c4cf0158db1a9a185dac","value":{"rev":"1-496c4d06dff82c1ad8a03cbcdf47f10b"},"doc":{"_id":"0006d0a04d14c4cf0158db1a9a185dac","_rev":"1-496c4d06dff82c1ad8a03cbcdf47f10b","topic":"iot-2/type/node-red-wiotp/id/f5f7aa27.368c48/evt/update/fmt/json","payload":{"value":0,"date_human":"2017-04-20T17:55:43.788Z","date_inmilli":1492710943788,"sensorType":"movement"},"deviceId":"f5f7aa27.368c48","deviceType":"node-red-wiotp","eventType":"update","format":"json","increment":0}}]}`

On sample output is this:

`Values                 Date
93       0                  1493750501405
94 c(1, 1491568686336)  c(1, 1491568686336)`

Comment: i forgot to specify that I used library(rjson) and library(gdata)

Comment: Providing sample data will be better. I generally use package `jsonlite` for json transformation and the `fromJSON` function generally gives a neatly nested list structure

Comment: You are right. Below there is an example of the 2 rows in the json_data.rows :

Answer (score 0):

Your sample data is missing a final "}". Here is a simpler approach. Use
`jsonlite::from_JSON` with `flatten = TRUE`. This makes for a consistent 
array structure that is easier to navigate with missing values 
filed with NA. Examine the structure with `str`

```
  library(jsonlite)
  myList <- fromJSON(json, flatten = TRUE)

  str(myList)
  # List of 3
  # $ total_rows: int 99019
  # $ offset    : int 0
  # $ rows      :'data.frame':  2 obs. of  20 variables:
  #   ..$ id                      : chr [1:2] "5f238411f1d877723c8e5f7a40c1fa3f" "0006d0a04d14c4cf0158db1a9a185dac"
  # ..$ key                     : chr [1:2] "5f238411f1d877723c8e5f7a40c1fa3f" "0006d0a04d14c4cf0158db1a9a185dac"
  # ..$ value.rev               : chr [1:2] "1-7625857a2f79af0e46c2b73fdbde986e" "1-496c4d06dff82c1ad8a03cbcdf47f10b"
  # ..$ doc._id                 : chr [1:2] "5f238411f1d877723c8e5f7a40c1fa3f" "0006d0a04d14c4cf0158db1a9a185dac"
  # <snip>
  # ..$ doc.sensorType          : chr [1:2] "movement" NA
  # <snip>
  # ..$ doc.payload.date_inmilli: num [1:2] NA 1.49e+12
  # ..$ doc.payload.sensorType  : chr [1:2] NA "movement"

  result <- data.frame(sensorType   = myList$rows$doc.payload.sensorType,
                       date_inmilli = myList$rows$doc.payload.date_inmilli)

  # sensorType date_inmilli
  # 1       <NA>           NA
  # 2   movement 1.492711e+12
```

Comment: Ok, but as you can see, the output is different from the one i specified. If I do this, I won't get value (not sensorType) and date_inmilli that are in the first observation.

Comment: From the str command you can see that there are 2 different paths to get the info i need:
myList$rows$doc.value, MyList$rows$doc.date_in milli  and
myList$rows$doc.payload.value, myList$rows$doc.payload.date_inmilli